# How to use constructor to set interfaces addresses?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, constructor

No really a problem, just need to understand a few things :

With this piece of code, transaction is reverted when calling "getEstimatedTokenForBNB" function.

```
// Initialize Parameters

constructor () {

    tokenAddress = 0xf63DB3cc676b71F8D38D27181d0AE9d7Aa4F1D48;
    wbnbAddress = 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd;
    pairAddress = 0xD280a7D55faa4a982616e8d5C6b2D68B5Ce366aF;
    routerAddress = 0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3;
    userManagementAddress = 0xa1eD4f05cE96241e75817765c78eFAA74a9c120C;
}

// Initialize Interfaces

IUserManagement USERMANAGEMENT = IUserManagement(tokenAddress);
IDEXRouter iROUTER = IDEXRouter(routerAddress);
IBEP20 TOKEN = IBEP20(tokenAddress);  
IBEP20 LPTOKEN = IBEP20(pairAddress);
IBEP20 WBNB = IBEP20(wbnbAddress);

// Modifiers 

modifier onlyToken() {
    require(msg.sender == tokenAddress); _;
}

// View Functions


function getEstimatedTokenForBNB(uint buyAmountInWei) public view  returns (uint[] memory) {

    uint[] memory bnbQuote;
    bnbQuote = iROUTER.getAmountsOut(buyAmountInWei, getPathForWBNBToToken());
    return bnbQuote;
}

// Utility Functions

receive() external payable {}

function getPathForWBNBToToken() public view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = wbnbAddress;
    path[1] = tokenAddress;
    
    return path;
}

function checkAmountValidity (uint buyAmountInWei) public view returns(bool checkResult) {
    try iROUTER.getAmountsOut(buyAmountInWei, getPathForWBNBToToken()) {
        checkResult = true;
        return checkResult;        
        }
    catch {
        checkResult = false;
        return checkResult;
        }
}
```

I found that if I set manually addresses in the // initialize Interfaces section, everything works as expected.. so I suppose that my constructor doesn't set the parameters at time.

Anyone can explain me the right way to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce your issue with the following example code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IInterface1 {
}

interface IInterface2 {
}
 
contract YourContract {

  address public address1;
  address public address2;

  IInterface1 public interface1 = IInterface1(address1);
  IInterface2 public interface2 = IInterface2(address2);

  constructor() {
      address1 = 0xf63DB3cc676b71F8D38D27181d0AE9d7Aa4F1D48;
      address2 = 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd;
  }
}
```

The problem is that all state variables are initialized at deployment time even before running the constructor, which is technically also part of the deployment process. Whether you want it or not, they are either set implicitly to 0 or to an explicit value if you provided one. So on deployment :

```
address public address1; // equivalent to address1 = address(0x0);
```

Followed by :

```
IInterface1 public interface1 = IInterface1(address1);
```

As address1 was initialized to 0, it sets `interface1` to the same value : 0.
Assignement from storage variable to storage variable always creates an independant copy ([documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html?highlight=storage#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour)). So, updating `address1` in the constructor has no effect whatsoever on `interface1`. Sticking to that (error-prone) design, you can either :

initialize everything at deployment time :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IInterface1 {
}

interface IInterface2 {
}
 
contract YourContract {

  address public address1 = 0xf63DB3cc676b71F8D38D27181d0AE9d7Aa4F1D48;
  address public address2 = 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd;

  IInterface1 public interface1 = IInterface1(address1);
  IInterface2 public interface2 = IInterface2(address2);

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Or initialize everything in the constructor:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IInterface1 {
}

interface IInterface2 {
}
 
contract YourContract {

  address public address1;
  address public address2;

  IInterface1 public interface1;
  IInterface2 public interface2;

  constructor() {
    address1 = 0xf63DB3cc676b71F8D38D27181d0AE9d7Aa4F1D48;
    address2 = 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd;
    interface1 = IInterface1(address1);
    interface2 = IInterface2(address2);
  }
}
```

Those are not the only possibilities, but I think they are the cleanest if you want to fit your current contract design.

To be honest, you don't seem to need the `address` "version" of your variables, as you can recover it from the interface on the fly if required. Rewriting my example :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IInterface1 {
}

interface IInterface2 {
}
 
contract YourContract {

  IInterface1 public interface1;
  IInterface2 public interface2;

  constructor() {
      interface1 = IInterface1(0xf63DB3cc676b71F8D38D27181d0AE9d7Aa4F1D48);
      interface2 = IInterface2(0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd);
  }
}
```

That way (or moving both initialization at the variable declaration) you don't duplicate what is essentially the same variable (target address) and you can use the interface type directly for clear external function calls.